# How does one add two buttons in same row of a panel?

Tags: extjs

How does one add two buttons in same row of a panel? (I'm new to extjs.)

Answer (score 2):

If by "add", you mean passing them to the constructor, just use an array in the `buttons` config:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'foo'
}, {
    text: 'bar'
}]
```

There's tons of examples on http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/

On the other hand, if you want to add buttons to an existing panel, you must actually add them to the panel's bottom toolbar (`bottomTb`) bar like so:

```
myPanel.bottomTb.add({xtype: 'button', text: 'foo'}, {xtype: 'button', text: 'bar'});
```

Note that `xtype` defaults to `'button'` and thus may be omitted

Answer (score 1):

You would use an Ext.Toolbar or container with an "hbox" layout.

The Toolbar is a built-in component that automatically stacks up buttons and fields into a horizontal layout, but it also changes the UI so that they "dock" visually.  You can see the docs to see what I mean, but it will look like a toolbar, not like two buttons next to each other.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html

To get two buttons side-by-side, say Ok and Cancel, you can use an hbox layout in 4.0.

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    items: [
        {xtype: 'button', text: 'Ok'}, 
        {xtype: 'button', text: 'Cancel'}
    ]
});
```

Check out the documentation for hbox for alignment and stretching options.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html

In older versions you'd do something similar, but with the less flexible 'columns' layout.